# Looking for suggestions on understanding a particular combinatorial optimization problem

Tags: algorithm, optimization, combinatorics, knapsack-problem, bin-packing

Given a set of items (sized anywhere from 1 to 100) and a number of bins (1 to 15.) Each item having a subset of bins the item can be assigned to and a preference ordering of which bin is best, second best, etc., just for it. Items also have a natural order, represented below by naming, e.g., item1 before item2. Each bin has a capacity between 1 and 5 (every item has identical weight, i.e., 1.)

An example input could be three bins and six items (- indicates a bin is not in the item's usable set, i.e., can't be packed with it):

```
      | bin1  bin2  bin3                        |  bin1  bin2  bin3   
------------------------               ----------------------------
item1 |    1     2     -               capacity |     4     4     5
item2 |    -     1     2               
item3 |    2     1     3
item4 |    1     2     3
item5 |    1     -     2
item6 |    1     2     3
```

The goals are (in order with each goal completely overriding any lower goal when there's a conflict, e.g., packing five items is always better than four no matter what number of bins are used or preferences ignored):

1. maximize number of items packed
2. pack items in their natural order, e.g., if total bin capacity is one and there are two items, item1 will be packed and item2 not
3. minimize number of bins used
4. pack each item according to its bin preferences and natural order, i.e, item1 in its first preference and item2 in its second is better than item1 in its second and item2 in its first
5. in cases where two solutions are indistinguishable by these goals, either solution is acceptable to rank higher, e.g, as a side-effect of implementation or just arbitrary tie-breaking.

So the input above would be packed as:

```
      | bin1  bin2  bin3
------------------------
item1 |    x            
item2 |          x     
item3 |          x     
item4 |    x          
item5 |    x      
item6 |    x
```

The question then is for what to read/review to help me come up with algorithm ideas for solving this problem with the input sizes from the first paragraph and a time constraint of a few seconds, i.e., not brute force (or at least any brute force I've conceived of so far.) I'm using Ruby and C but language isn't overly relevant at this stage of woods stumbling.

I'll be grateful of any reading suggestions, ideas on combinations of algorithms, or just thoughts on clarifying the problem statement...

**Update 1**

To be less unclear, while there are many algorithms that cover various parts of this my difficulty is in finding (or perhaps recognizing) information handling all the criteria together, especially minimizing the number of bins used when there is excess capacity and conflicting item-to-bin sets and item preferences, which is hopefully more clearly shown in the following example:

```
      | bin1  bin2  bin3                        |  bin1  bin2  bin3   
------------------------               ----------------------------
item1 |    1     2     3               capacity |     3     2     3
item2 |    1     2     3          
item3 |    -     1     2
```

While bin1 is the most preferred, item3 can't be placed in it at all, and while bin2 is the next most preferred for all items, it can hold only two of the three items.  So the correct set of assignments (x) is actually the least preferred bin:

```
      | bin1  bin2  bin3
------------------------
item1 |               x  
item2 |               x  
item3 |               x
```

**Update 2**
I reworked the description with information on how the goals relate and removed the variable of bin priority as it only makes finding an answer less likely and can be worked around elsewhere in the system I'm working on.

Comment: The problem seems to fit neatly into an integer programming scheme, so if your instances are small, the fastest solution is probably just to close your eyes and use an IP solver first. If that doesn't solve it fast enough, you can always try to go for a more specialized algorithm.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good point about just giving IP a go, just in case. Will do.

Comment: In the second paragraph, you've specified at least three different objectives: 1) maximize number of items packed, 2) maximize bin utilization, and 3) minimize number of bins used. You can either rank these objectives or define some trade-off between them. You can't really throw out three possibly conflicting objectives and leave it at that.

Comment: Thanks @mhum, that's a good point. I reworked the description with information on objective ordering.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want to optimize. Will having empty bins always trump bin preferences? i.e. even if some bin is very preferred for some item, it's still better to place it in another bin if that means that you need fewer bins in total?

Comment: @Jules: Yes, a solution that uses fewer bins is preferred no matter how the item's preferred bins conflict with the result; I updated the description to cover that. (Note an item can't be placed in a bin unless its in the usable set, regardless of goals.)

Comment: @Yuri: This is certainly an improvement, but there remains a gap. Suppose you have two possible assignments that are equal in every respect (e.g.: number of items packed, number of bins used, etc...) except for one -- in assignment 1, items 3 and 4 are packed but in assignment 2, items 2 and 5 are packed. Which assignment is to be preferred?

Comment: Simiarly, suppose you have two assignments equal in every respect except that one has every item assigned to its second choice while the other has half the items assigned to their first choice and the other half to their third choice. Ordinal data (i.e.: ranked preferences) need rigorous specification to make your optimization problem well-defined.

Comment: @mhum Great points. In both cases it would not matter which was chosen, or even if the same choice where made each time, i.e., the choice of one over the other is expected to be a side-effect as even the end-user doesn't have a logical reason to prefer one or the other. In an algorithm that might fail, e.g., infinitely recurse, I would use a trivial tie-breaker, e.g., first solution set in the list of solutions or the first set by first item order (**2**,5 over **3**,4 instead of the goal's 2+5=7 and 3+4=7.)

Comment: To add to what @mhum was saying: If 2 solutions are equal on criteria 1, 2 and 3, there needs to be some way of getting a *total order* on assignments of items to bins.  The usual way is by scoring possible assignments.  E.g. by the number of items in their most-preferred bins, breaking ties by the number of items in the 2nd-most-preferred bins and so on.  Is that what you want?  Because other criteria are possible: e.g. you could stipulate that...

Comment: ...  a solution in which item i is placed in its most-preferred bin and item j is not is preferable to the reverse whenever i < j (this gives lower-numbered items priority).

Comment: @j_random_hacker, @mhum: Thanks both, I realized what I really had was an unwritten ass-umption about the relationship of the second and fourth goals, which j_random_hacker points out right above. Updated the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose there are n items and b bins, and each bin has size s.  The ordering of constraints you have added actually simplifies the problem a great deal.

They mean specifically that we should always pick items 1, 2, ..., m for the largest m <= n that will fit in the allotted number of bins (since picking a smaller number would necessarily produce a worse solution by rule 1).  Items will be packed in bins in this order, possibly with some bins left incompletely filled (since rearranging items within a bin or across bins would produce a worse solution by rule 2).  There are 2 cases:

1. m < n, meaning that we can't fit all the items.  In that case, all b bins will be tightly packed with the 1st m items in that order, and we are done.
2. m = n, in which case we can fit all the items.  We now consider subcases of this case.

In this case, it may be possible that packing bins tightly will leave a final block of 0 < e <= b of the bins completely empty.  In that case, discard those final e empty bins and proceed (since using more bins would produce a worse solution by rule 3).  In any case, call the final number of bins remaining r.  (r = b - e.)

We now know exactly which items and which bins we will be using.  We also know the order in which the items must be packed.  Because of the ordering constraint, we can regard the decisions about which bins are to be left incompletely filled as the problem of **how to inject "start-next-bin" instructions into the ordered list 1, 2, ... n of items**.  We can inject up to r-1 of these instructions.

This problem can be solved in O(nrs) time using dynamic programming.  Essentially we compute the function:

**f(i, j, k) = the score of the best solution in which the first i items occupy the first j boxes, with exactly k items in the jth box.**

The recurrence is:

```
f(i, j, 0)     = max(f(i, j-1, k)) over all 0 <= k <= s
f(i, j, k > 0) = f(i-1, j, k-1) + q(i, j)
```

Where q(i, j) is the quality score of assigning item i to box j.  (As I mentioned in the comments on your post, you need to decide on some way to assign scores for a placement of any item i into any box j, presumably based on how well i's preferences are met.  If it's easier to work with "badness" values than quality values, just change the `max()` to a `min()` and the `-infinity` boundary values below to `infinity`.)

The first equation says that the best score of a solution for the first i items whose rightmost bin is empty is equal to the best score that can be found by considering every solution for the first i items without that bin.  These candidate solutions consist of all the ways that the previous bin can be packed, including leaving it empty too.

The second equation says that the best score for the first i items whose rightmost bin is not empty is found simply by adding the quality score for placing the last item to the best score for placing the first i-1 items in the same number of bins.

The boundary conditions are:

```
f(0, 0, 0) = 0
f(i, 0, k) = -infinity for all other i and k
```

After calculating the values of f(i, j, k) for each 0 <= i <= n, 0 <= j <= r and 0 <= k <= s and storing them in a table, f(n, r, s) will give the optimal score of the final solution.  Although this only gives the score of the maximum, the actual optimal solution(s) can be found by tracing back through the f(i, j, k) matrix from the end, at each k = 0 step looking for the predecessor state (i.e. the alternative under the `max()`) that must have led to the current state.  (It may happen that several alternatives under the `max()` give equal scores, in which case multiple optimal solutions exist, and any of these paths can be followed to find just one of them.)

Comment: This is really helpful. One point I'm fuzzy on is the statement in para 3 that "and which bins we will be using." I don't see how bin selection is done prior to that, or did you mean "and how many bins..."?

Comment: Unfortunately your changes make it clear that I have misunderstood what you meant by your rule 2.  It's now clear that by rule 2, you don't mean "pack items in their natural order" (which I interpreted to mean that item 3 will always appear in a bin <= to the bin in which item 4 will appear) but instead "If only m < n of the n items will fit, then prefer a solution in which just the first m items are packed *in some order*".  That means my DP algorithm doesn't apply.

Answer (score 1):

This reminds me of the ["Match" algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Resident_Matching_Program#Matching_Algorithm) used to place medical school graduates in residency programs.     What if you treat the items like students, their bin preferences like the rank lists, and the bins like hospitals?

Basically, you go through the list of items, and for each item, find the bin it prefers most.  Check with the bin:  *do you have room for this item, and if not, do you prefer it more than any items you currently have?* 
If no, cross this bin off the item's list, and move to the item's next choice.
If yes, place this item in the bin, and put the displaced item (if any) back in the unmatched pool.

The difference between your problem and the residency match is that you wouldn't fix the bin's preferences up front. Instead you would use a rule that prefers items that bring the bin closest to 100% full.

My only concern is that this modification might make the algorithm unstable.  But it's such a simple algorithm, it's probably worth trying.

Comment: Oh, I misread and assumed that items had different sizes. If they are all the same, than I would make the bin preference rule something like "if full, kick out an item who's next choice is a higher priority bin".   Note that this gives higher weight to the item preferences than to the bin priorities.

Comment: Thanks, I stupidly skipped past this algorithm early on but you make good points about its applicability. And, this works great if there are more items than bin capacity. What I'm still thinking through is the tricky part you allude to, i.e., how to handle scenarios with more bin capacity than items. I'll update this if I figure anything out.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bipartite matching problem and can be solved in polynomial time.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)#Maximum_matchings_in_bipartite_graphs

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't looked at this as edge matching, which is helpful. Most of what I found from that as a starting point didn't quite cover the bin packing aspects of my conundrum, e.g., assignment problem and the Hungarian solution. Still looking through it though.

Comment: My idea was to represent each bin of size n by n separate minor bins, and put each item in one of them. Then you could directly apply the hungarian algorithm. But you seem to want to minimize the number of big bins, so I don't immediately see a solution. Perhaps you can call the hungarian algorithm multiple times restricted to different subsets of bins to solve your problem.